# Light dims when i turn on my light on my new ceiling fan

Tags: electrical, wiring, led

Ok I switch all light ceiling fixtures with new led ceiling fixtures and a new ceiling fan in my room when i turn on my ceiling fan. The lights on 3 of my other rooms ceiling led light dim. I don't know what the problem would be but it's only on the rooms not the hallway or the kitchen or the downstairs  living room anyone can help thank you.

Comment: What make and model are the fixtures and fan in question?

Comment: The fan is a hunter apex2 from Costco and the lights are from there too but they don't have bulds straight LEDs

Comment: We *especially* need make/model/instructions information for the fixtures then